# Rename Columns of dataframe based on names of list in R

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, mapply

I have multiple dataframes saved in a list object. They share the same two column names. I'd like to rename the second column to the name of the dataframe.

Example Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B= 11:20)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 21:30, B = 31:40) 
df3 <- data.frame(A = 31:40, B= 41:50)
df4 <- data.frame(A = 51:80, B = 61:70) 

listDF <- list(df1, df2,df3, df4)
```

I'm trying to use lapply to rename the second column to match the name of the dataframe.

```
# trying to rename second column after the element of the list they're located in
listDF_2 <- lapply(names(listDF), function(x) setNames(listDF[[x]], x) )
```

Comment: Your list doesn't look like it has names. What does `names(listDF)` return for you? After you make the listDF, it doesn't keep track of the names "df1", "df2", etc anymore. At least not how you have it written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep track of names, you can use:

```
listDF <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3  = df3, df4 = df4)
```

Then you can use for loop:

```
for (i in names(listDF)){
  colnames(listDF[[i]]) <- c("A", i)
}
```

Or if you need to use lapply, you may use this:

```
newDF <- lapply(names(listDF), function(x){
  colnames(listDF[[x]]) <- c("A", x)
  listDF[[x]]
})
names(newDF) <- names(listDF)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may like to use `dplyr::bind_rows` in this case. It simplifies using name of the data.frames as a new column in combined data frame.

```
# Create list as.
listDF <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2,df3 = df3, df4 = df4)

library(dplyr)

# Now combine all data frames. The name of data frame will be in 'DF_Name' column
bind_rows(listDF, .id = "DF_Name")

#    DF_Name  A  B
# 1      df1  1 11
# 2      df1  2 12
# 3      df1  3 13
# 4      df1  4 14
# 5      df1  5 15
# 6      df1  6 16
# 7      df1  7 17
# 8      df1  8 18
# 9      df1  9 19
# 10     df1 10 20
# 11     df2 21 31
# 12     df2 22 32
# 13     df2 23 33
#.................
#.................
# 58     df4 78 68
# 59     df4 79 69
# 60     df4 80 70
```

**Note:**  As `@Moody_Mudskippe` has pointed out that one can simply use

```
listDF <- lst(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

and then use `dplyr::bind_rows`.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Ohh. You are correct. Now I have realized what you meant to point out.